# How to Get both Notification and data when app is background in android

Tags: push-notification

How to Get both Notification and data when app is background in android.

When app is foreground than get both Notification and data.

But when app in background than get only data.

I want Get both Notification and data when app is background.

Comment: What have you done?

Answer (score 1):

As i searched it's not possible.
you can pass Notification parameters to data and get them in

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
 createNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}
private void createNotification(Map<String, String> data) {
....
 NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon)
            .setContentTitle(data.get("title"))
            .setContentText(data.get("body"))
}
```